# How to I find records by the id of parameter from another collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```js
var ObjSchema = new Schema ({
    productId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "M_Data_Product", default: null},
    qty: {type: Number, default: 0},
    price: {type: Float, default: 0},
});
```

This is my cart model

```js
var ObjSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, default: null},
    categoryId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "M_Data_Category", default: null}
});
```

This is Product model.

I want to cart records by particular categoryId. How should I find?

Comment: Can you please add an input example of your documents and expected output?

Comment: Cart.find({'productId.categoryId': req.params.categoryId})
I'm trying like this. But not working.

Comment: Is something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OlVPWHPB63y) what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
 "from": "Product", //collection name of product
 "localField": "productId",
 "foreignField": "_id",
 "as": "product"
}
  },
  {
    $match:{"product.categoryId":"exampleId"}
  }
])
```